# Search a field for a word that is an string

Tags: sql-like, contains

Hi i need to search a field for a word that is an string, the field might have multiple words seperated by comma

```
strA = Pass

strSQL = "Select `First`, `Last`, `Grade` FROM `Student` WHERE Grade like'"%&strA&%"'"
```

it errors what have i got wrong please or am i using like wrong and is there another one like contains

thanks michelle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT()` function to combine percent operators with the parameter :

```
strSQL = "SELECT `First`, `Last`, `Grade` FROM `Student` WHERE `Grade` like CONCAT('%', @strA, '%')"
```

From the syntax, it seems you're using MySQL as DBMS. So I reflected the parameter's prefix with `@`

Comment: thankyou - i think ive got an error in the coding above where this is in my project as that makes sense but not working -

Comment: you're welcome @user3567211 . What occurs if you convert `@` to `&` ? Btw, what's your DBMS?